# Windows API for detecting out of paper on specific printer tray

Tags: c#, printing

I'm looking for a way to determine if a specific tray on a given printer in Windows is out of paper.  Currenly I'm using the WMI Win32_Printer object to get the status of the entire printer, and if one of the trays is out of paper I do get a status that tells me the entire printer is out of paper.

But I'd like to know if a specific tray is out of paper.  Copious Google searches have come up with nothing.

I'm writing the app in c# but pointers to examples in any language would do.

Thanks, in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because they are usually hardware specific interfaces.  If you use one hardware vendor like HP or Dell then you can probably find a way to figure this out.  But the Windows interface seems to only allow notification of the printer being totally out of paper.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this but I seem to recall you can do it via SNMP.